# How to build multilingual Crystal reports

Tags: winforms, crystal-reports, localization, multilingual

We are developing a multilingual Winforms application using visual studio 2008. I am trying to figure out how I can create multilingual reports using crystal Reports.

Is there any thing similar to .net resource files in the Crystal reports world?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sorry that I'm robbing you of your tumbleweed badge, but I don't think Crystal has the multiple language support similar to .NET. I think that your only option is to have a separate report for each language and pass the data into the report in the language that you wish to display.

Here is a link of a similar answer. 
http://www.dbforums.com/crystal-reports/991737-crystal-report-multillingual-support.html

Answer (score 0):

This would be a manual way of doing this:

1. Create a report for each language you want and put into the proper folders structure. i.e. all japanese reports will go into rpt_ja/ folder.

   [image: Report folder structure]
2. Use .Net Resource file to specify report resource name and full resource name for each language:

   - resource.resx

     RPT_SAMPLE       -> report01.rpt

     RPT_SAMPLE_FULL  -> MyCompany.NameSpace.Reports.Report01.rpt
   - resource.ja.resx

     RPT_SAMPLE       -> rpt_ja\report01.ja.rpt

     RPT_SAMPLE_FULL  -> MyCompany.NameSpace.Reports.Report01.ja.rpt
3. Then use this value in the report code file: Open the report .cs file and change:

   ```
   public override string ResourceName {
   get {
       // Change this to HttpContext.GetGlobalResourceObject("Resource", "RPT_SAMPLE").ToString();
       return "report01.rpt";
   }
   set {
       // Do nothing
   }
   ```

   }

   ```
   public override string FullResourceName {
       get {
           // Change this to HttpContext.GetGlobalResourceObject("Resource", "RPT_SAMPLE_FULL").ToString();
           return "rpt_ja\report01.ja.rpt";
       }
       set {
           // Do nothing
       }
   }
   ```

EDIT: HttpContext is for ASP.Net web application. In winform, you can try Properties.Resources.ResourceManager.GetString() to get the string from resources

Answer (score -1):

A client ask me for a solution to this issue.  I developed a solution based on Crystal Reports contentLocale keyword and Custom Functions.  See my posting: http://www.cogniza.com/blog/?p=55.