# Crystal Reports in Visual Studio 2008 and Localization

Tags: visual-studio-2008, crystal-reports, localization

I can't seem to find any information about localizing reports created with Crystal Report that ships with Visual Studio 2008.  How do you change the reports to be localized?  Do they use resx files?  Any links to where to find out more information about how localization using Crystal Reports in Visual Studio 2008 would be very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea solution will allow the localization to occur in the Crystal Reports viewer control.  It will rely on using:

- 'System Default [data type] Format' for date, currency, or numeric data
- the ContentLocale function and custom functions: see http://www.cogniza.com/blog/?p=55

The CR viewer dynamically localizes reports (using the workstation's settings) with fresh or saved data when the report is displayed.  This means that reports that are run 'on demand' or 'scheduled' (using the BO Enterprise terminology) are treated consistently.

Textual data, like comments or notes, however, will be especially challenging.  Either you will need to dynamically translate the text or save it in a translated state in another column.  Most likely, you will need to use a parametrized report to do this type of localization, thus negating the usefulness of the CR viewer.

Answer (score 1):

This question was asked a little while back. Hopefully someone will have a better answer than this one.

[How to build multilingual Crystal reports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1037751/how-to-build-multilingual-crystal-reports)