# Crystal Reports Localization

Tags: crystal-reports, localization

We're developing an existing application with C# 2.0 and Crystal Reports for Visual Studio 2005. The problem is we want to localize the report dynamically. How to achieve it in Crystal Reports 2005?
So if the current culture is "id-ID", I want my report to display "Rp" instead of "$" , and the date format in in Indonesian format.

Comment: See this answer if it help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27497402/856540

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're building these reports in the Report Designer, right-click on each field in question and select Format Field... . Select the date or number tab as appropriate, then click the Customise... button. Each of the properties you would need to change - thousands separator, decimals separator, currency symbol, DMY order, etc. - can be specified by clicking the formula button for that property, and entering an appropriate formula.

Obviously, you will need to have some way for Crystal to determine that the current culture *is* eg. "id-ID" - I suggest that this should be by passing the culture value to the report as a parameter. (An alternative would be to include a culture column in the report's datasets, but this would leave the culture undefined for datasets with 0 records.)

I think it should be possible to automate all of this through the API.